# Multiple icons in executable in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, icons, exe

I have Googled and found multiple ways of adding multiple icons into the executable, but they all seem to work for VS 2003-2005-2008, nothing for VS2010. I have not tried the Win32 resource with /win32res because I do not know how to use it (can't figure to get a good Google result for that either).

Any simple suggestion?

Comment: I'm interested in this answer aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/160885/How-to-Embed-Multiple-Icons-and-Color-Animated-Cur.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I've just created a simple tool to do exactly this without having to mess with .res files. It's a tiny utility which you can use as part of your Post-Build event and lets you add all icons files in a particular folder to your assembly. If we assume that you have a icons folder under your main project folder you can add the following post-build event:

```
C:\path\to\InsertIcons.exe $(TargetPath) $(ProjectDir)icons
```

A further description and a download can be found at http://einaregilsson.com/add-multiple-icons-to-a-dotnet-application/

Answer (score 0):

#### If you're using visual studio 2012:

- **For C#.NET** [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19580/Embedding-Multiple-Icons-into-NET-Executables) I found a good solution for this problem for c# projects as an example. But it only works in my C# projects

  > 1. Create a new "Native Resource Template" from the File | New dialog box.
  > 2. In project properties(project->application->resources) there is option to choose `resource file (.res)` rather than "Icon and manifest" which is selected by default (This option is visible only to C# projects!).
- **For VB.Net** projects [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/160885/How-to-Embed-Multiple-Icons-and-Color-Animated-Cur.aspx) link (Also mentioned here by Waldo) can be more helpful because in my visual 2012 there is no option to select/browse `Native Resource Template(.res)` files but you could manually change project definition file for vb.net project as described to compile project win a native win32 resource file:

  > Open your project file in notepad (*.vbProj) and add the following block:
  >
  > ```
  > <PropertyGroup>
  >     <Win32Resource>assemblyWin32.res</Win32Resource>
  > </PropertyGroup>
  > ```

Answer (score 0):

The Code Project article explains how to create a "assemblyWin32.res" file.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/160885/%2fTips%2f160885%2fHow-to-Embed-Multiple-Icons-and-Color-Animated-Cur